# How do I remove the left padding in this layout?

Tags: css

My site, www.whatsthatbug.com, is a wordpress blog. I have combed through all of the CSS, and I cannot figure out how to get rid of the extra space on the left side of the page. Any suggestions would be most welcome.

Comment: I just looked at your page and I dont know how you expect anyone to help you without posting code and expecting us to ungarble your sites html/css to help you.

Comment: @Iznogood It's surprisingly easy with Firebug.. Just hover over the right area, and there's your CSS!

Comment: @James I know but he could of made an effort. But point takenm i gave him his point back why not. If the community agrees with him.

Answer (score 2):

Here's your problem:

```
body div#wrapper {
    margin: 1em 0px 0px 7em;
}
```

Your wrapper has a left margin of 7em. Try the code below:

```
body div#wrapper {
    margin: 1em 0px 0px 0px;
}
```

Comment: I apologize to everyone for the sloppy way I asked the question. I had forgotten that all of my html and css is minified now, and thus unfriendly to read.

I had a blind spot - the div#wrapper tag was being overridden in functions.php. I changed it there, and it aligns properly now.

Thank you for your assistance!

Answer (score 1):

thethimble is right: it's the 7em left margin on #wrapper.

How to find this yourself: get [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com), then you can hover over elements and see their attributes.  In the CSS tab, you'll be able to edit CSS values live and see their effect on the page.

Answer (score 0):

You have `body div#wrapper{margin : 1em 0 0 7em}`. The 7em is assigning a left margin to the page is #wrapper is the encompassing div.